# How to create a RDS Cluster inside a VPC?

Tags: amazon-rds, boto3, amazon-vpc

I'm using boto3 [`create_db_cluster`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.create_db_cluster) to create a RDS cluster. How can I create a the cluster in a non-default VPC?

Already tried passing `VpcSecurityGroupIds` which are in the target VPC, but got the following error:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred
>   (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the CreateDBCluster
>   operation: Database is in vpc-X, but Ec2 Security Group sg-Y is in
>   vpc-Z

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer.

We first need to create a DB Subnet Group that contains subnets in the target VPC, then pass the group name in the `DBSubnetGroupName` param. This will create the cluster in the target VPC.